# Unity3d - Camera rotation smoothing 'bug'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a simple *racing* game. The camera follows the car (player) and its position and rotation is based on car's Y rotation. I want to smooth the camera rotation, but when it crosses 0 degree point, it rotates 360 degrees.
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform camera, player;


    void Update() {
        Vector3 cameraPosition = camera.transform.position;
        float cameraRotation = camera.eulerAngles.y;
        float playerRotation = player.eulerAngles.y;
        Vector3 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        cameraPosition.x = (Mathf.Sin((playerRotation / 180) * Mathf.PI) * -6 + player.position.x);
        cameraPosition.y = playerPosition.y + 2.5f;
        cameraPosition.z = (Mathf.Cos((playerRotation / 180) * Mathf.PI) * -6 + player.position.z);
        camera.transform.position = cameraPosition;
        cameraRotation = cameraRotation + (playerRotation-cameraRotation)/2;
        camera.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(20f, cameraRotation, 0f);
    }
}
```

I figured out that this rotation is caused by smoothing script:

```
 cameraRotation = cameraRotation + (playerRotation-cameraRotation)/2;
```

How to prevent this unwanted rotation?

Comment: What kind of formula is that rotation based on? Do you want the camera to look at the car? Also, why not just child the camera onto the car so you dont have to mess with the Sin and Cos?

Comment: The camera acts almost like a child, but I want to add this smoothing to make it looking a little bit better. Yes, I want camera to look at the car. There's no problem with Sin and Cos, but with the smoothing script. It looks like this: [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WQdJvdv9xVSvXitZEkImZwQXvF112mKz)

Comment: Also, you can do `cameraRotation = cameraRotation + (playerRotation-cameraRotation)/10;` to make it slower and more visible.

Comment: I know there's no problem with Sin and Cos. It's just unnecessary in my opinion since you get a similar effect just by putting your camera as a child of the car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
public int smoothSpeed = 1f; // Change accordingly to increase/decrease smooth speed.
```

Then in update:

```
Vector3 directionToCar = player.position - camera.position;
Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToCar);
camera.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(camera.rotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime * smoothSpeed);
```

On a side node, if this camera script is attached to the camera, you don't have to make a field referencing the camera's transform. You can simply do `transform.position` instead of `camera.transform.position`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution to using the Slerp is to use Mathf.SmoothDamp, which has a variant called Mathf.SmoothDampAngle which handles the looping correctly. I've also had success doing the wraparound by hand but its not a very rewarding experience

```
using UnityEngine;
public class RotFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform carTransform;
    [SerializeField] float smoothTime = .4f; 

    float currentYAngle;
    float targetYAngle;
    float angleVel;
    void Update()
    {
        targetYAngle = carTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        currentYAngle =  Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentYAngle, targetYAngle, ref angleVel, smoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
                                        transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
                                        currentYAngle, 
                                        transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
        }
    }
```